# OpenLayers 3 support for WMS 1.3.0 CRS:1

Tags: wms, openlayers, tiles

I am trying to get a TileWMS layer working with the Coordinate System as CRS:1 defined in WMS 1.3.0. By defining the right projection stated in CRS:1, axisorientation as 'es', I could get it working for ImageWMS. However, when using TileWMS, I found all the tileGrids defined in OpenLayers 3 are always aligned with 'en' direction. tileindex x increments as x goes right, tileindex y increments as y goes up. So it is different from the CRS:1 definition. This causes the tiles are put into wrong direction in y axis.

My question is that is there any way that I can change tiling direction to follow the axixorientation defined in my projection, in this case, is 'es'?

Or is there any advice or examples for 'es' projection like CRS:1 in tiled API of OpenLayers 3?

Comment: The tilegrid axes are fixed as Openlayers should create the correct tile urls (in the case of WMS that means calculate the bbox) from the tilegrid coordinates based on the resolution and the supplied projection definition which must specify any axis swap or reversal.  Do you know of any publicly accessible 'es' projection WMS services which could be tested?